# Style tag in head of HTML email not parsed

Tags: email, stylesheet

How can I get email clients like Gmail's web interface to parse `<style>` declarations placed in the head of a well formed HTML email?

Also, can I force background images on tables to be shown, or that's just something some will show and others will not?
For example this gets ignored:
`background:url(http://mysite.com/background.gif) repeat 0 0 #FFFFFF;`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if you want to send and email formatted with CSS you need to built it in the HTML, rather than use

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood, I thought you were placing the css on an <link rel="stylesheet"> this won't work, but you are already placing the CSS on the <style>.

Comment: Yeah, I have styles in a <style> tag that's in the head of the document.